# How do I loop code to produce 4 graphs instead of 1?

Tags: r

```
N <- 10000 ; maxbound = 20 

one_side_normal <- function(N) {
  f <- numeric(N);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    X = rexp(1,rate=1);
    uniform = runif(1);
    while (uniform>exp((-X^2)+X) ){
      X = rexp(1,rate=1);
      uniform=runif(1);
    }
    f[i] <- X
  }
  return(f)
}

sample = one_side_normal(N) ;
hist(sample,breaks = seq(0,max(sample)+0.04,0.04), xlim = c(0,maxbound),freq = FALSE) ;
x = seq(0,maxbound,0.01) ;
lines(x,sqrt(2/pi)*exp((-x^2)/2), col = "red")
```

The above code creates a histogram from a sample of 10000 (N=10000) using the Acceptance-Rejection method of sampling. How would I loop this code to create 4 different histograms for sample sizes 10,100,1000 & 10000?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the whole thing in `for`. You can use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` to plot 4 graphs at once.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(N in c(10,100,1000,1000)){
maxbound = 20 
sample = one_side_normal(N) ;
hist(sample,breaks = seq(0,max(sample)+0.04,0.04), xlim = c(0,maxbound),freq = FALSE,
     main = paste("Histogram of Sample Size",N)) ;
x = seq(0,maxbound,0.01) ;
lines(x,sqrt(2/pi)*exp((-x^2)/2), col = "red")
}
```

[image]

No need to define the `one_side_normal` function 4 times, so you can leave it outside the loop.

```
one_side_normal <- function(N) {
  f <- numeric(N);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    X = rexp(1,rate=1);
    uniform = runif(1);
    while (uniform>exp((-X^2)+X) ){
      X = rexp(1,rate=1);
      uniform=runif(1);
    }
    f[i] <- X
  }
  return(f)
}
```

One other thought, I recommend not defining variables that share the
symbol of base R functions. Otherwise you'll risk confusing `sample` with `sample()`.